# Add Automatic hot spare to Windows raid5

Tags: windows, raid5

Ive been searching all over and cant find anything on this subject. I have a Raid 5 configured in Server 2003 using 3 1.5Tb drives, I have a 4th drive I want to add as a hot spare and I would need to use the spare automatically if one of the drives fail. Is this even possible in a windows raid?

Comment: When you say Windows RAID, are you talking about the software RAID?

Comment: Yes, Im using the raid 5 function built into Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hot-spare and hot-swap drives are features of hardware RAID controllers

Comment: So there's no way to designate a 4th drive as a spare for it to rebuild on?

Comment: Replace failed disk with your 4th and rebuild.